# smoothly object transition through lerp and coroutine

Tags: unity, c#

```
IEnumerator SmoothlyShiftPosition(Vector3 destination, float OverTime) {

    float startTime = 0;
    while (startTime < OverTime)
    {
        Debug.Log(startTime/OverTime + "changing: " + navigationCanvas.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("startTime : " + startTime);
        navigationCanvas.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(navigationCanvas.transform.position, destination, startTime/OverTime);
        startTime += Time.deltaTime * 2f;
        yield return null;
    }
    navigationCanvas.transform.position = destination;
}
```

I have this simple code snippet which i am using to lerp my object to specfied position smoothly it work sometime correctly but  not always. I logged different data and **found that my startTime variable sometime *becomes zero* continuously**. I am unable to figure why this occuring? what i am doing wrong?

Edit:

I am calling coroutine function like this

```
 if (SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum != null) {
                            StopCoroutine(SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum);
                        }
                       SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum = StartCoroutine(SmoothlyShiftPosition(navCanvas, smoothPositionTime));
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not calling the coroutine multiple times?

Comment: @Nikaas good point i am checking that if coroutine is already running then sop it. like code updated above

Comment: I don't think this change will fix it. You may need to add `SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum=null` at the end of the coroutine. Then only start the coroutine if SmoothlyShiftPositionIEum is null.

Comment: You might find [the pattern described in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136748/39518) helpful. Be sure to check whether you're pausing the game anywhere by setting Time.timeScale to zero. This will pause any script that uses Time.deltaTime, making it idle in the same place until the time scale is restored.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan
If the Lerp part is working as intended you can ignore this. 

It's worth mentioning that you aren't "linear interpolating" since you constantly change the starting position of the lerp. If you want a true linear transition from A -> B you need to save your starting position and use that as value A. By using your modified position in the lerp value you'll actually get a curve transition where things speed up as they approach the target. Once again, if this what you want, the go for it. Just making sure.

Comment: @Nikaas the null check is only to confirm that i dont call double corroutine

Comment: @DMGregory thanks but i am not pausing my game anywhere. Additionally thanks for you another linked answer, can't you  identify the error in my own code?

Comment: @Zebraman thanks for your advice if there is any problem in my code or provide your alternative in the answer section. thanks

Comment: Not without seeing where you call it. The best hypothesis I've seen so far is that this coroutine is being cancelled and restarted every frame.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes i am calling my coroutine in update but it only happen for few frame as raycast stop hitting my desired object. my coroutine get called. This is why i used if check

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan As it is, when you call the new coroutine it resumes from where the previous one left (was stopped) but with one difference - the timer is reset. In the end if there are unintended coroutine calls happening you will have to find why and prevent them.